# BlackBerry persistent-store data lost after OS update

Tags: blackberry, operating-system, persistence, startup

I am creating a BlackBerry application that starts automatically when the device starts, and it uses the persistent store to hold data.

After updating the OS version, the application does not run on startup and if I start it manually, there is no data in the persistent store, and the program crashes.

So what is happening...
1. when auto-run setting is lost during OS update?
2. when persistent storage is lost?

and how do I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

To have persistent data survive an OS upgrade you will have to use the synchronization API. The OS upgrade process does a data backup (using the synchronization API), copies installed third party applications off the device, wipes the device, installs the new OS then installs third party applications and resores data (again with the synchronization API). The API is documented at: [Backing up data](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/17952/Backing_up_data_1219851_11.jsp).